# How to join two lists and fill a datagridview

Tags: c#, linq, list, join, datagridview

I have two list (1st with values from a website, 2nd with values from a .csv file) and I'd like to join them in another list, starting two equals values, and display it in a datagridview.

Before to post the code, I'd like to say that I tried to fill my datagridview with these two lists separately and they work.

I didn't get any error, but I can't see my datagridview with values.

I'm going to post my code and explain it.

First List Code:

```
var url = textBox5.Text;
        //var url = "http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/norway/tippeligaen/results/";

        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load(url);

        Bets = new List<Bet>();

      

        // Lettura delle righe
        var Rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr");

        foreach (var row in Rows)
        {
            if (!row.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("rtitle"))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.InnerText))
                    continue;

                var rowBet = new Bet();
                foreach (var node in row.ChildNodes)
                {
                    var data_odd = node.GetAttributeValue("data-odd", "");

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data_odd))
                    {
                        if (node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("first-cell"))
                        {
                            rowBet.Match = node.InnerText.Trim();
                            var matchTeam = rowBet.Match.Split(new[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            rowBet.Home = matchTeam[0];
                            rowBet.Host = matchTeam[1];
                        }


                        if (node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("result"))
                        {
                            rowBet.Result = node.InnerText.Trim();
                            var matchPoints = rowBet.Result.Split(new[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            int help;
                            if (int.TryParse(matchPoints[0], out help))
                            {
                                rowBet.HomePoints = help;
                            }
                            if (matchPoints.Length == 2 && int.TryParse(matchPoints[1], out help))
                            {
                                rowBet.HostPoints = help;
                            }

                        }


                        if (node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("last-cell"))
                            rowBet.Date = node.InnerText.Trim();
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rowBet.Odds.Add(data_odd);
                    }
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rowBet.Match))
                    Bets.Add(rowBet);
            }
        }
```

Second List & Combined List Code:

```
 string FileName = @"C:\mydir\testcsv.csv";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection
           ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " +
             Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName) +
             "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");

    conn.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter
           ("SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileName(FileName), conn);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Temp");
    adapter.Fill(ds);

    conn.Close();

    // DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

    //dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
    // dataGridView2.DataMember = "Table";


    List<HT> matchlist = new List<HT>();
    matchlist = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                   select new HT()
                   {
                       Home = dr["Home"].ToString().Replace("Milan", "AC Milan").Replace("Roma", "AS Roma"),
                       Host = dr["Host"].ToString().Replace("Milan", "AC Milan").Replace("Roma", "AS Roma"),
                       ScoreHome = dr["ScoreHome"].ToString(),
                       ScoreAway = dr["ScoreAway"].ToString(),
                       //Segno = dr["Segno"].ToString(),
                       //odd1 = dr["odd1"].ToString(),
                       //oddx = dr["oddx"].ToString(),
                       //odd2 = dr["odd2"].ToString()

                   }).ToList();

   

   // dataGridView2.DataSource = matchlist;

    var combinedDataList = (from d1 in Bets
                            //join d2 in dataList2 on d1.Home equals d2.Home
                            join d2 in matchlist on new { d1.Home, d1.Host } equals new { d2.Home, d2.Host }

                            select new CombinedData
                            {
                                Data = d1.Date,
                                Home = d1.Home,
                                Away = d1.Host,
                                HSFT = d1.HomePoints,
                                ASFT = d1.HostPoints,
                                HSHT = d2.ScoreHome,
                                ASHT = d2.ScoreAway,
                                HODD = d1.odd1,
                                XODD = d1.oddX,
                                AODD = d1.odd2,
                                RisFin = d1.RisFin,
                                Over05SH = d1.over05sh,
                                Over05FT = d1.Over05FT,
                                Over15FT = d1.Over15FT,
                                Over25FT = d1.Over25FT,
                                Over35FT = d1.Over35FT,
                                Over45FT = d1.Over45FT

    
                            }).OrderBy(p => p.HODD);
    dataGridView2.DataSource = combinedDataList;
```

Thank you for your attention. Have a fantastic sunday!

**EDIT:** I delete unnecessary code

**EDIT2: I add the screen of my single list output. Let's see:**

First List:
[image]

Second List:

[image]

So, I'd like to merge "ScoreHome" and "ScoreAway" from the second list in my first list based on "Home" and "Host" that I have in both lists.

Comment: Please make your question concise and ask only the required details, like post first list schema and second list schema and also the result schema on combining two lists. Whole code is not required, it makes it difficult to follow your requirements.

Comment: I think you have deleted the required information, now I don't know what's the schema of First and Second list, your current code is not important, its important to understand input and expected output

Comment: Ok, I edited my post and I added outputs screenshots. Thanks again!